# "Couldn't install App on device" error message

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, gradle, visual-studio-code

When I try to run a simple React Native app from Visual Studio Code, I get below error message.

```
Scanning folders for symlinks in C:\Projects\MobApp\Project2\sampleapplication\node_modules (286ms)
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug)...
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip

Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: services.gradle.org
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:59)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:46)
at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:46)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:126)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

I have made sure that the emulator is running, which I got from installing Android Studio.

Result after running react-native info:

```
Environment:
OS: Windows 7
Node: 9.11.1
Yarn: Not Found
npm: 5.6.0
Watchman: Not Found
Xcode: N/A
Android Studio: Version 3.1.0.0 AI-173.4720617

Packages: (wanted - installed)
react: 16.3.1 -- 16.3.1
react-native: 0.55.4 -- 0.55.4
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment? DId you?

Comment: Yes, like i have specified in the comments i have made sure emulator is running

Comment: What result did you get with "adb devices" command?

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions on `android/gradlew`

they should be `755` not `644`

run

```
chmod 755 android/gradlew
```

inside your app root folder and then run

```
react-native run-android
```

Comment: i have tried this and i think its for Linux os not for Windows. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

issue got resolved.
It was due to proxy issues.Our company has some settings which is blocking the use of android studio.
After adding proxy in Gradle.properties file it started working

Thanks